# Darkening Image in Python

Tags: python, image

This code works, it returns the image, it is just not darkened like it should be. Any ideas on this one?

```
from cImage import *

def darkenPixel(factor, pixel):

    pixel = Pixel(r, g, b)
    r = pixel.getRed()
    g = pixel.getGreen()
    b = pixel.getBlue()

    while r <= 255:
        pixel.setRed(100)
        while g <= 255:
            pixel.setGreen(150)
            while b <= 255:
                pixel.setBlue(150)

def darken(imageFile):

    myimagewindow = ImageWin ("Image Processing", 400, 400)

    oldimage = FileImage(imageFile)

    oldimage.draw(myimagewindow)

    width = oldimage.getWidth()
    height = oldimage.getHeight()
    newim = EmptyImage(width, height)

    darkenPixel

    newim.setPosition(width + 1,0)
    newim.draw(myimagewindow)
    myimagewindow.exitOnClick()
```

Comment: It's strange that it works at all.  You're not copying any pixels from the old image to the new.  The darkenPixel function, which is not clear in itself, is never even called.

Comment: The Readme of your library is [https://github.com/bnmnetp/cImage/blob/master/README.rst](here). There is a code example that could get you started in your problem.

Comment: From the readme and some other context I found, it seems that `cImage` is designed as a very simple image manipulation library, to be used _only_ in the context of "an introductory computer science course". If this is the case, to give you the most appropriate answers it could be helpful to know if it is a course about image manipulation or a course about python.

Comment: @Photon, it's not so much it works. It opens the file in a new window and such, however it's just not darkening the image like we are wanting it to.

Comment: @Gboffi, it is a basic python course, however our instruction isn't exactly the best. This section/assignment is just about image manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

You're never *calling*  `darkenpixel()` in your code. You're just creating a reference to it and discard it immediately afterwards.

So you would at least need to iterate over all the pixels and call `darkenpixel()` using the current pixel and the darkening factor on each one.

However, your function `darkenpixel()` is not going to work as-is. First, you're overwriting the `pixel` parameter immediately at the start of the function, and you never even use `factor`. Then, you're using `while` loops where an `if` statement would be necessary, and you're nesting those loops without any reason.

I guess you should think a bit more about your approach to the problem (and maybe read a basic [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/index.html)) before working on such a complex problem...

Comment: If the code were correct, the semantic would be obscure, as the logical tests _as written by the OP_ are always true and consequently all the pixels would be set to `(100,150,150)`, a darkish cyan if that matters...

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker
So basically in the main function darken it would read:

darkenPixel()
     then right here it would have to actually darken each and every pixel right?

Also, this is for a basic python course however the instructor doesn't do much instructing thus why I am here asking for help. I also have to use while loops per the instructions, even though a for loop would be much better off here.

Comment: @gboffi -- the color doesn't really matter, it just needs to darken the image.